# FuelCMS echo the page body content that was set in admin page panel

Tags: php, codeigniter, fuelcms

I tried setting up a content in the Body:
[image]

I wanted to echo that content in my `elson.php` file

So this is my simple code

```
<?php echo fuel_var('body', ''); ?>
```

The problem is that I don't get the `test` word that I set on the admin panel. Why is that?

Any help on this. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your elson.php file won't be called as it's using the main.php layout.